# Is Procfile supported in EB PHP platform?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, procfile

I've trying to start a process using Procfile without sucesss. I'm using Amazon Linux 2 with PHP Platform in Elastic Beanstalk.
Here is the test Procfile I'm using trying to debug:

```
web: bash -c "while true ; do date ; sleep 1 ; done"
control: python3 controlHub/controlCenter/control.py
bashtest: bash -c "while true ; do date ; sleep 1 ; done"
phptest: php -r 'while (true) { echo date("Y-m-d h:i:s") . "\n"; sleep(1); }'
```

The deployment works fine and Wordpress website is running ok. I can see in */etc/rsyslog.d/web.conf* that the logs redirection were created. However there are no log files for those Procfile processes in */var/logs* and *systemctl status* shows those processes are not running.